# GitHub API: how to get total number of accessible repositories

Tags: rest, api, github-api

What is the GitHub API endpoint that provides the info on the TOTAL number of repositories a user has access to?

I don't just mean repos that the user owns, or repos the user has as public, I mean ALL repos. Basically, the same list that user would see when browsing the repos on GitHub.com when logged in.

I know how to get a list of those, but that's limited to 100 at a time. Is there an API endpoint that would simply return the TOTAL number of them, without my having to retrieve all of them and count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) would allow such a query with a "total number" request.

You can [test queries in developer.github.com](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/).

The query using repositories is only for repos accessible by a user, not for *all* GitHub repos. ([`RepositoryConnection`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/repositoryconnection/))

```
query {
  viewer {
    repositories(isFork: false) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

But for *all* repositories, you would need to use [Google BigQuery GitHub Data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github), which you can start exploring though [`dataset/bigquery-public-data:github_repos`](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/bigquery-public-data:github_repos).

Comment: Thank you!\ for the answer! Much appreciated!